# I got the following quiz question wrong: Does {} ∈ (1,2)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was asked this question on a quiz and stated that this statement was true. My logic being, $\{\}$ is an element in all sets. The ordered pair can be rewritten as $\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$ as a set. What is wrong in my thinking? The teacher has not provided me with a proper explanation.

Comment: "*{} is an element in all sets*"  No, incorrect.  The empty set is not an *element* of most sets.  It happens to be a **subset of** every set... but being a **subset of** and being an **element of** are two distinctly different properties.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you for your response. I am new to set theory and I apologize for my ignorance! I definitely confused the symbols ∈ and ⊆.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please accept an answer if it answers your question. To help you use this site for future questions, please learn to use MathJax here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  You can start by improving this question by editing it. You can see an example of MathJax by clicking on "edit" under the posted answer, to see how the answerer used MathJax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty set $\emptyset = \{\}$ is *not* an element of every set (though it is a *subset* of every set).

The only elements of $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ are $\{a\}$ and $\{a,b\}$, which are not empty.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This makes sense, I confused the symbols ∈ and ⊆. (I'm new to set theory)

Comment: $\emptyset$ is an element of the set $\big\{\emptyset\big\}$, but there does not exist any element that belongs to $\emptyset$.